# detect a returned message via ajax on third party js

Tags: javascript

I have a page that embeds a .js hosted elsewhere. This .js has a button that triggers an action on the server and return a success message on my page inside a specific `div`.

How can I detect when this message arrives and replace it with another `div` that I provide?

Comment: no, only returns a div inside my page.

Comment: Please post some code so we can understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: I can't show the .js code but basically its a hosted .js file that display a button on page, when clicked performs an ajax call and returns a div on my page. My question is how can I detect a div that has been placed after it has been placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener) suggests a DOM change event is in bleeding-edge browsers. So you could listen for that if you use the supporting browsers only.

Otherwise, you may need to set a recurring timer ([setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)) to periodically check if the div has changed, and then react to this.

A third possibility is finding out how the external script actually uses the DOM node you pass to it. You could create a shim object with any luck. E.g., if the external script assigns to `innerHTML` to set the content, then you could pass a dummy object to the external script, and react to a 'fake' `innerHTML` property being set. This would probably use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

A fourth approach could be to find out how the external script communicates with the server, and add a layer of indirection. E.g. if external script uses `$.ajax`, then replace this with your own code that can detect the particular signature of the external script's request.

A fifth approach is to overwrite the external script's button-click functionality. E.g. if the button-click function calls a global `externalScriptButtonClick` function, then overwrite this. This would probably only work if you have visibility on this code, and not if it's 'private' and wrapped in a closure, for example.